# (Android) Webview much slower than Browser on loading iframe

Tags: android, iframe, webview

I have a webview and I need to use the soundcloud iframe
if i start 
diskover.altervista.org/lol.html
in the webbrowser it starts the song fast
If I start it in the webview (with javascript enabled) it takes much more seconds

How can I solve the problem?